# How to set initial camera position (Three.js/VR)?

Tags: three.js, virtual-reality, perspectivecamera, oculusgo

If I do not set initial position to the camera, the WEB borwser and Oculus Go browser behave differently (see images below).

```
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, width / height, 1, 1000 );
// camera position is Vector3(0, 0, 0)
scene.add( camera );
```

[image: Initial camera position in WEB browser]

Pic. 1 - Initial camera position in web browser (e.g. Google Chrome)

[image: Initial camera position in VR browser]

Pic. 2 - Initial camera position in VR browser (e.g. default browser of Oculus Go)

It looks like `Three.js`'s scene knows in which environment it runs and automatically adjust the camera position. How can I change the initial position of the camera?

Currently, I am doing somethink like this:

```
const cameraHolder = new Group();

cameraHolder.add(camera);
cameraHolder.position.set(0, 1, 0);

scene.add(cameraHolder);
```

but again, it doesn't resolve the issue with different positions in different environments.

Comment: Do you have a working example of this bug? Additionally, you don't have to add your camera to the scene hierarchy. You can simply change its position without `scene.add(camera)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the behaviour of the reference space. If you use reference space type of `*-floor` the device knows about how tall you are. The camera y is then set to your device y position, which makes sense. As I couldn't find where to grab the device height from I just set the reference space type to local.

```
this.renderer.xr.setReferenceSpaceType( 'local' );
```

For me the `scene.add(cameraHolder)` was necessary, otherwise the camera wouldn't receive the position/rotation. Old HMDs had the cameras attached to a "head" model, then you would turn the head instead of the camera.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`renderer.xr.addEventListener()`

**Example**

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, width / height, 1, 15);
camera.position.set(0, 0.6, 3); // Set the initial Camera Position.

const cameraGroup = new THREE.Group();
cameraGroup.position.set(0, -1, 1.5);  // Set the initial VR Headset Position.

//When user turn on the VR mode.
renderer.xr.addEventListener('sessionstart', function () {
    scene.add(cameraGroup);
    cameraGroup.add(camera);
});
//When user turn off the VR mode.
renderer.xr.addEventListener('sessionend', function () {
    scene.remove(cameraGroup);
    cameraGroup.remove(camera);
});
```